# Example of Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Seek separable solutions, $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ of the equation, $u_{tt}=c^{2}\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$. Find the general solution assuming the separation constant is zero.

I am only able to get as far as $X(x)T''(t)=c^{2}\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$, in which I'm unsure on how to proceed afterwards. When I referred back to an example of applying the separation of variables method to the diffusion equation, it was possible to express the equation $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ in the form $\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\dfrac{T'(t)}{DT(t)}=k$ where $D$ is the diffusion constant, and $k$ an arbitrary constant. I wonder if this is also possible for this specific problem, or am I supposed to follow another procedure? I appreciate any pointers I can get on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$c^2\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})=c^2\frac{1}{x}\big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\big)=c^2T(t)\frac{1}{x}\big(X'(x)+xX''(x)\big)$$

So the partial differential equation can be rewitten as

$$X(x)T''(t)=c^2T(t)\frac{1}{x}\big(X'(x)+xX''(x)\big)$$

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{1}{xX(x)}\big(X'(x)+xX''(x)\big)=K$$

where $K$ is the separation constant. But we assume that $K=0$ so we have

$$T''(t)=0 \space\space\space\text{and}\space\space\space xX''(x)+X'(x)=(xX'(x))'=0$$

That is $T(t)=a+bt$ and $X(x)=c_1+c_2\ln(x)$ for constants $a,b,c_1,c_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has been helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right) = \frac{1}{x} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right)$$
Therefore the equation becomes
$$X(x) T''(t) = c^2 \left(\frac{X'(x) T(t)}{x} + X''(x) T(t) \right)$$
You can divide both sides of this equation by $X(x) T(t)$ to separate variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has been helpful.